# How to merge multiple functions into one function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if I can optimaze the follwoing functions into one or two functions instead of four. Here is the link to the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-microservice-jprqq?file=/src/components/forms/form-multi-step-login/multi-step-login-form.component.jsx)

```
  // Proceed to next step
  const firstStep = (firstName, lastName) => {
    setInputValue((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      step: prevState.step + 1,
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
    }));
  };
  // Proceed to next step
  const secondStep = (email, password) => {
    setInputValue((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      step: prevState.step + 1,
      email: email,
      password: password,
    }));
  };

  const thirdStep = () => {
    setInputValue((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      step: prevState.step + 1,
    }));
  };

  const fourthStep = () => {
    setInputValue((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      step: prevState.step + 2,
    }));
  };
```

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by merging these functions? They all appear to do *slightly* different things. Is it a typo for the `fourthStep` function to add 2 to the step?

Comment: @DrewReese the fourth one is not a typo. You are right. All of these functions do slightly different things. I was thinking that I am doing something wrong if I repeat the functions with a small difference in what they achieve

Comment: Well, if the goal is to be more DRY then you can identify what is "abstractly" the same functionality, like incrementing the step by *some* amount, and updating *some* state. I think @CertainPerformance is onto it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to make a function which, given a step increment count and a new object to merge with the existing state, calls `setInputValue` with the required combined object:

```
const setStep = (newProps, stepIncrement) => {
  setInputValue((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    ...newProps,
    step: prevState.step + stepIncrement,
  }));
};
```

Then instead of `firstStep(firstName, lastName)`, you can do `setStep({ firstName, lastName }, 1)`, and so on.

Since you're using hooks, another option would be to use separate state variables and functions:

```
const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
// etc
```

```
const firstStep = (firstName, lastName) => {
  setFirstName(firstName);
  setLastName(lastName);
  setStep(step + 1);
};
const secondStep = (email, password) => {
  setEmail(email);
  setPassword(password);
  setStep(step + 1);
};
const thirdStep = () => setStep(step + 1);
const fourthStep = () => setStep(step + 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

from my view

```
const step = ({ firstName = "", lastName = "", email = "", password = "", step = 0 }) => {
  setInputValue(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    step: prevState.step + step,
    firstName: firstName || prevState.lastName,
    lastName: lastName || prevState.lastName,
    email: email || prevState.email,
    password: password || prevState.password
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I tried to resolve your dilemma.

```
const nextStep = (newValues, incrementCount) => {
setInputValue((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  ...newValues,
  step: prevState.step + (incrementCount ? incrementCount : 1)
}));
};
```

You can see full code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-fast-ihu0d?file=/src/components/forms/form-multi-step-login/multi-step-login-form.component.jsx:567-773).